# How can you quit from dialog in C# bot-framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm starting a project for a ChatBot in C# with the bot framework.

I choose the `ContosoFlowers` example for learning about the use of bot framework. In the `AddressDialog` users cannot quit the dialog after they enter to it without providing an address.

How can I update the code so when users reply "Cancel" or "Abort" or "B" or "Back" they quit the dialog?

```
namespace ContosoFlowers.BotAssets.Dialogs
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Extensions;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
    using Properties;
    using Services;

    [Serializable]
    public class AddressDialog : IDialog<string>
    {
        private readonly string prompt;
        private readonly ILocationService locationService;

        private string currentAddress;

        public AddressDialog(string prompt, ILocationService locationService)
        {
            this.prompt = prompt;
            this.locationService = locationService;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync(this.prompt);
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;

            var addresses = await this.locationService.ParseAddressAsync(message.Text);
            if (addresses.Count() == 0)
            {

                await context.PostAsync(Resources.AddressDialog_EnterAddressAgain);
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else if (addresses.Count() == 1)
            {
                this.currentAddress = addresses.First();
                PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.AfterAddressChoice, new[] { Resources.AddressDialog_Confirm, Resources.AddressDialog_Edit }, this.currentAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                var reply = context.MakeMessage();
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;

                foreach (var address in addresses)
                {
                    reply.AddHeroCard(Resources.AddressDialog_DidYouMean, address, new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Resources.AddressDialog_UseThisAddress, address) });
                }

                await context.PostAsync(reply);
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }

        private async Task AfterAddressChoice(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            try
            {
                var choice = await result;

                if (choice == Resources.AddressDialog_Edit)
                {
                    await this.StartAsync(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Done(this.currentAddress);
                }
            }
            catch (TooManyAttemptsException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tasks are a part of .NET, they have nothing to do with bots. Google for task cancellation, CancellationToken etc. Be aware though that cancelling a task that awaits a response from a remote service does *NOT* send any specific message to that service. It simply cancels the wait. If you want to tell the Bot service to terminate a dialog, you need to find and call the proper methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to handle the quit conditions at the top of the `MessageReceivedAsync` method.

At the top of the dialog you can add something like

```
private static IEnumerable<string> cancelTerms = new[] { "Cancel", "Back", "B", "Abort" };
```

And also add this method:

```
public static bool IsCancel(string text)
{
   return cancelTerms.Any(t => string.Equals(t, text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Then is just a matter of understanding if the message sent by the user matches any of the cancelation terms. In the `MessageReceivedAsync` method do something like:

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
   var message = await result;

   if (IsCancel(message.Text)) 
   {
     context.Done<string>(null);
   }

   // rest of the code of this method..
}
```

You can also go a bit more generic and create a CancelableIDialog similar to what was done in the [CancelablePromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs).

Comment: try 'context.Done<string>(null);'